# Embedding an external XML file

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, file, relative-path

Right, so I have a program that reads from an external XML file to get details of students. Currently it is set to a full path such as: `C:\Users\LittleJohnny\Students.XML`. I'm in the process of making this program independent (set all the videos to `Always Copy` so that they'll run properly on different machines), I was wondering if I could put the XML file in a relative location as well, so that it would work on different machines. I'm sure there is an easy way to do this.

Comment: Place this XML file in your `Output` folder of your application.

Comment: And then would I just use `Student.XML` as the path?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the Special folders path like this one : "Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData".
It allow you to set path to folders relative to the current system which runs the applications.

More information [there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx)

In code, this would be :

```
path = Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments + @"\Students.xml";
```

If you want to store it in the current user's documents, for example.